# Framework7 / video.js touchevent conflict

Tags: video.js, html-framework-7

The sourcecode is here [sourcecode](http://runjs.cn/detail/navng62a)。

The pc mode is operating normally, but it is not working properly in mobile mode. I run the above program in chrome。

It is not working when i click the play/pause button,but when i long press the button,everything is ok.

I find the reason,but i dont know how to reasonably solve the problem.

In framework7`s touchend event it call [sendclick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjHLj.png) method.In video.js there is a 
pseudo-event ["tap"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qh5s.png).

when i touch the screen,it called "touchendevent" twice,as it called the framework7's click method and video.js`s tap method.

I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcDFf.png) .tap and click event is called in same time 。so the video is playing first，but it pause suddenly，because the second event called。[code in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Bhy.png)

If i long press the button,it is working fine because the tap‘event is not called。

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself。

videojs.getComponent('Component').prototype.emitTapEvents = function () {}

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `touchTimeThreshold` from 200 => 20. But this needs to change in library. Better to add this following lines before initializing videojs:

`videojs.getComponent('Component').prototype.emitTapEvents = function () {}`